# Springtool suite STS 4.6.1 RELEASE not launching, progress bar stays midway forever

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, version

```
  Log Error. As suggested by others I used the 64-bit versions of STS and Java version. Here's the   log error from my local directory C:\APPS\sts-4.6.1.RELEASE\.metadata\.log file
```

### !SESSION 2020-05-12 18:28:02.540 ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.202004200639-RELEASE java.version=1.8.0_161 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2020-05-12 18:28:30.543 !MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the key bindings from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' and 'org.eclipse.ui.bindings' extension point !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2020-05-12 18:28:30.543 !MESSAGE Defining a key binding with no key sequence has no effect: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard', id='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.addStarersSwitchHandler' !SESSION 2020-05-12 21:41:33.247 ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.202004200639-RELEASE java.version=1.8.0_161 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64